# vi bindings in ndk-gdb

Tags: android-ndk, gdb, vi, ndk-gdb

I know `C+M+j` enters into vi-mode in gdb.  Cygwin-gdb seems to obey my shell settings (`set -o vi`) and automatically is in vi-mode.  However, I can't seem to get ndk-gdb to get into vi-mode.  Does anyone know how?